How to remove string + n preceding characters from pandas dataframe
I have a dataframe that looks like the following:
Group Attribute Text
1     A         'The ball is red456placeholder'
1     A         'I like pizza985placeholder.'
2     A         'Fire bad 231placeholder'
2     B         'Sparkling water makes me happy777placeholder'

I want to clean the text column and remove the occurrence of the word placeholder but also the three spaces in the string preceding it.
I understand how to remove the placeholder text:
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('placeholder','')

Then, I'm left with the final column with the number on the end.  I've tried:
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'^\d+\s+', '', regex=True)

This doesn't seem to have any effect.  Is there a better way to do this?

df['Text'].str.replace(r'\s*\d*placeholder', '', regex=True)? See https://regex101.com/r/WEVQZK/1

What is your desired output from that input?

If you just want to remove the three characters before, this seems like the easiest way:
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('placeholder','').str[:-3]


print(str.replace('placeholder',''))

print(str.replace(r'placeholder',''))

Use anyone of this solution
